# A neater way of handling bools in C#

Tags: c#, boolean, nullable

Working with nullable bools in C# I find myself writing this pattern a lot

```
if(model.some_value == null || model.some_value == false)
{
    // do things if some_value is not true
}
```

Is there a more compact way to express this statement? I can't use non-nullable bools because I can't change the model, and I can't do this

```
if(model.some_value != true)
{
    // do things if some_value is not true
}
```

Because this will throw a null reference exception if `model.some_value` is null

One idea I had:
I could write an extension method for bools like `String.IsNullOrEmpty` - `bool.IsNullOrFalse`. This would be neat enough but I'm wondering if there's some more obvious way of doing this already?

Comment: second code block work perfect. Why you did get null reference error. https://dotnetfiddle.net/yf1bro

Comment: Did you try #2? It should be working fine..

Comment: @JenishRabadiya from msdn - _"If the HasValue property is true, the value of the current Nullable<T> object can be accessed with the Value property. Otherwise, attempting to access its value throws an InvalidOperationException exception. "_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor did you looked at fiddle I provided. It works why would we aceess its value? second code block does not access it.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya is right, it does work there. Apologies

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I made the poor assumption that it was using Mono and discounted the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a null-coalescing operator to handle cases where the value is null.

```
if(model.some_value ?? false != true)
{
    // do things if some_value is not true
}
```

From msdn:

> ### ?? Operator (C# Reference)
>
> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the
>   left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the
>   right hand operand.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Alternatively, a `switch` would do it.

```
switch(model.some_value)
{
    case false:
    case null:
    // do things if some_value is not true
    break;
}
```

Comment: why simple condition(model.some_value != true) wont work? look at this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/yf1bro